# Getting comma separated values from PHP array

Tags: php

I have an array thusly

```
$main_array = [

    ["image" => "james.jpg", "name" => "james", "tag" => "spacey, wavy"],
    ["image" => "ned.jpg", "name" => "ned", "tag" => "bright"]
    ["image" => "helen.jpg", "name" => "helen", "tag" => "wavy, bright"]

]
```

I use a `foreach` to echo some HTML based on the value of `tag`. Something like this

```
    foreach($main_array as $key => $array) {        
        if ($array['tag'] == "bright") { 
            echo '<p>'.$array['name'].' '.$array['image'].' '.$array['tag'].'</p>';
        }
    }
```

This only outputs "ned" as matching the tag "bright". But it should output "helen" too. Similarly:

```
    foreach($main_array as $key => $array) {        
        if ($array['tag'] == "wavy") { 
            echo '<p>'.$array['name'].' '.$array['image'].' '.$array['tag'].'</p>';
        }
    }
```

Should output "james" and "helen". What kind of function do I need to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking an item in a list of items, you can use `explode()` to split it into parts (I've used split by `", "` as each item seems to have a space as well) and then use [`in_array()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if it is in the list...

```
if (in_array("bright", explode( ", ", $array['tag']))) {
```

Comment: yes, this is the right answer. heavy day at work, this was the answer I wanted to give too

Comment: Yes, that's it. I was reading about `explode` but I'm just a hobbyist and still learning. I think I was close with other trial and error but maybe got the syntax a little wrong. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You cant do it directly, because it return key with values in string. Below are the working code.

```
<?php
   $main_array = [

    ["image" => "james.jpg", "name" => "james", "tag" => "spacey, wavy"],
    ["image" => "ned.jpg", "name" => "ned", "tag" => "bright"],
    ["image" => "helen.jpg", "name" => "helen", "tag" => "wavy, bright"]

];

foreach($main_array as $key => $array) { 
    $str_arr = explode (", ", $array['tag']);
    foreach ($str_arr as $key2 => $array2) {
        if ($array2 == "wavy") { 
            echo '<p>'.$array['name'].' '.$array['image'].' '.$array['tag'].'</p>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```